# turn right backward or turn slightly right backward?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, direction

[image: An intersection of four roads, looking kinda like the Union Jack (a saltire plus a cross). An arrow is coming up from the south, making a sharp angle in the middle of the intersection, and exiting to the southeast.]

Please see the image. When giving directions, how should I describe what the arrow indicates on the road?
My ideas are

1. turn right backward
2. turn slightly right backward

I'm not sure if they make sense.

Comment: Turn sharply on your first right should cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a curiosity, for the "standard" answer to such questions:

you have to look at the sentence formulas currently read by the two major GPS (sat-nav) makers, TomTom and Garmin.

There is no reason you would do anything other than what the two major platforms do, as a matter of safety and consistency.

It's an interesting curiosity that that is sort of the "new OED", for such issues :)

Exactly as Erik said, AT A ROUNDABOUT as far as I know both major platforms would say "in about 1 kilometer, at the roundabout, take the first exit".  (I'm pretty sure they state the situation first, rather than "take the first exit at the roundabout")

The OP has said it's not a roundabout, then indeed I think both platforms say [actually I don't remember; but you should use that as your guide].

For whatever software you are working on you should strongly consider the current Garmin/TomTom formulas.

Comment: For hell's sake, vote up my answer dude!  We only do this for poitns! Just joking, but as a new user it is Worthy to vote answers and TICK an answer, as it gives you "points" so you get less moderated, etc, in the future

Answer (score 1):

If there is a roundabout in the middle of that crazy intersection, then "Take the first exit" will cover it. Otherwise, "Turn hard right".

Comment: thank you for the answer. *the case is not about roundabout.

Comment: If it were, and you were in Britain (or most English-speaking countries) it would be the FIRST exit!  But 'turn very sharp right' is the way I would direct anyone. It is also the way my sat-nav says it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does 'Turn very sharp right' sound formal to English speakers? I'm looking for the right expression that can be used for voice navigation service.

Comment: @WS2 - Actually, it would be the SEVENTH exit (remember, in Britain traffic flows clockwise round a roundabout because you drive on the left). Meanwhile, I assumed the hypothetical driver was driving on the right, because the arrow seems to be a tad closer to the right-hand side of the road than the left. But I agree that 'turn very sharp right' (and variations on that theme) is a good answer.

Comment: @Canvas - I'd say it is very well suited to a navigation service. Because it centres on a technical instruction, it is neutral in tone.

Comment: it's complicated, there could be more than one sharp right.  the computer formula has to always work.  programming language is tough. {I mean, "making those decision so that it always is clear to the user" is tough. the literal programming is trivial.}

Comment: @ErikKowal Sorry I meant to say 'wouldn't be the first exit'!